# Passing resultset's column int value into a C# list

Tags: c#, list, int

I am passing variables from a List class to a C# gridview. All is going well except when I include database column that returns an int value. How do I pass the resultset's column value into the list? the column that's causing the error is the "local" variable.

```
public class shuffleDataList
{
    public string directLine { get; set; }
    public int local { get; set; }
    public string employeeNumber { get; set; }
}


        List<shuffleDataList> callList = new List<shuffleDataList>();

            if (rdr != null)
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                { 
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {   
                        callList.Add(new shuffleDataList()
                        {
                            directLine = rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? null : rdr.GetString(0),
                            local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : rdr.GetInt32(1),
                            employeeNumber = rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? null : rdr.GetString(2),
                        });
                    }
                }
```

the code will return:

> *"Specified cast is not valid."*

I have tried already GetInt32 (as per code above) but still not solving the issue. Again, how do I pass the resultset's column int value into the list? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is it the line `local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : rdr.GetInt32(1)` and are you sure it always contains an `Int32`?

Comment: code looks fine, data might contain a string and not int? In this case, you'll have to parse it

Comment: What type does column with index 1 have (add `rdr[1]` into watch list and look at the result)?

Comment: `GetInt32` gets the column value as `Int32` type so i don't think your column with index **1** contains a value that can be converted into integer.

Comment: hi. the 

local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : rdr.GetInt32(1),

is where my problem lies. the local variable was named after a column named "Local" on my query. The column is of numeric datatype for which I assumed using int datatype on C# will retrieve it

Comment: @SurajSingh the column value is of numeric type? What do you suggest I used in c# to handle it? Seems int is not for this kind of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my earlier dilemma of passing numeric data from a db table column to a C# list

Instead of using this:

```
local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : rdr.GetInt32(1),
```

I experimented and used this instead:

```
local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(rdr.GetValue(1)),
```

thanks to everyone who tried to solve my issue.

Comment: Good you solved your issue +1, So what was your type i mean numeric(n,n) ? just make sure you have whole number in your entry or it will cause precision related issues .but i think you must be having only whole numbers.

Comment: @SurajSingh yeah, the db table column is of numeric data type and only accepts whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
...
local = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : Parse(rdr.GetString(1)).GetValueOrDefault(0),
...

static int? Parse(string value)
{
    int result;

    if (int.TryParse(value, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: sorry but it returned:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.

the 'local' variable is named after a column named Local of numeric datatype